# CNTK LSTM How to define data of sequence to sequence

Tags: c#, lstm, cntk, recurrent-neural-network

When my data looks like this:

```
1      |x 3:1 |y 8:1
1      |x 4:1 |y 
1      |x 5:1 |y 
1      |x 6:1 |y 
1      |x 7:1 |y
```

And my variables are declared like this:

```
var features = Variable.InputVariable(new int[] { inputDim }, DataType.Float, featuresName, null, true);
var labels = Variable.InputVariable(new int[] { numOutputClasses }, DataType.Float, labelsName, new List<Axis>() { Axis.DefaultBatchAxis() }, true);
```

Then the code works, but when I want my network to produce sequence --> sequence so my data looks like this:

```
1      |x 3:1 |y 4:1
1      |x 4:1 |y 5:1
1      |x 5:1 |y 6:1
1      |x 6:1 |y 7:1
1      |x 7:1 |y 8:1
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 
The dimension size (5) of the axis (1) of the Value ('[10 x 5 x 20]') 
must be 1, because this axis is not specified as a dynamic axis of 
the Variable ('Input('labels', [10], [#])').
```

How do I tell CNTK that this is ok, I want output at each step along the sequence so I think it should have this data, this is a classic many to many LSTM.  But either the CNTK c# api is broken, or I just don't know how to tell it what I want to do (most likely).

10 inputs, 10 outputs, 5 elements in the first sequence, 20 sequences in my batch.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to remove: `new List<Axis>() { Axis.DefaultBatchAxis() }`
from the labels, as the default is to allow a sequence, and that means 'this is not a sequence', doh!

e.g.

```
var labels = Variable.InputVariable(
                 new int[] { numOutputClasses },
                 DataType.Float,
                 labelsName,
                 null,
                 true
             );
```

As an aside, you must ensure your network model doesn't destroy the sequence too so don't use `CNTKLib.SequenceLast(LSTMFunction)` :-)

Thanks to KeDengMS for explaining the issue to me :-)